# Observable between library - Angular 11+

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe, angular11, npm-package

I have three library that communicate each others some data. In particular I have a **MAP** that show some positions with markers, a **TABLE** that show details of each markers and the third library (we call it **SHARED**) have some service and observables that let to map and table to communicate each other.
For example

1. MAP (click a marker and recall a service of SHARED)
2. SHARED make a next on observable send id of marker
3. TABLE is listening, receives id and underline the row of the corresponding marker

I'll show some code of this communication:

1. MAP recall SHARED when marker is clicked

```js
this._dataSharedService.sendIdMarker(idMarker);
```

2. SHARED do next

```js
private idMarker: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(undefined);
sharedIdMarker = this.idMarker.asObservable();

sendIdMarker(idMarker: number) {
  this.idMarker.next(idMarker);
}
```

3. TABLE receives

```js
this.sharedIdMarkerSubscription = this._dataSharedService.sharedIdMarker.subscribe(idMarker => {
  if (idMarker !== undefined) {
    console.log(idMarker);
    this.selectedRowId = idMarker;
  }
});
```

I have no problems when I use Angular 10.0.4 and I compile my library normally:

```sh
ng build library_name
cd dist/library_dir
npm pack
```

When I pass to another project with Angular 11.2.10 I have to build my TABLE library with this option in tsconfig.lib.json

```json
{
  ... ,
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

otherwise I get this error when I start the application

```sh
ERROR Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Expecting flags [Expected=> number === boolean <=Actual]
```

At the same time I have to compile MAP library with the same option but setted to true otherwise I get this error when I build the library

```sh
Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol 'AppConfigService'
Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the value of this variable is needed by the template compiler.
```

Compiling library in this way, I'm able to run the application but this particular observable not work!
**NOTE** that there are other observables from MAP to TABLE and also from TABLE to MAP always passing from SHARED (same structures showed before) and all they work correctly!!
I test also to subscribe directly my application to these observable but not even the application receives the id of marker.

Someone know why this specific observable not work only when I pass to Angular 11?

**PS.** since my first project was in Angular 10 my libraries are written in Angular 10, then I pass to a project with Angular 11 and I would to use the same libraries (that work perfectly even for this observable)

Comment: Why not enable Ivy everywhere and resolve the errors that show up instead?

Comment: If I enable Ivy (enableIvy: true) for TABLE library I get the error written in the answer.
(ERROR Error: ASSERTION ERROR: Expecting flags [Expected=> number === boolean <=Actual])  
If I disable Ivy (enableIvy: false) for MAP library I get the error written in the answer.
(Error encountered in metadata generated for exported symbol 'AppConfigService'
Metadata collected contains an error that will be reported at runtime: Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the value of this variable is needed by the template compiler.)

Comment: Yes, so resolve those errors instead of ignoring them. Surely there's other people who's encountered the same issues, just google them.

Comment: I'll try to solve them, but however I don't understand why all the other observables work correctly

Comment: do the working observables use the same service or another one?

Comment: Other observables are in the same service and they are declared in the same way. For example I have another observable that instead of send only one id of the single selected marker, let me to select multiple markers with a box and then send an array of id to table. The same communication described before with the only difference of argument of the BehaviorSubject<number[]>